# Condition in Select statement….. T SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, bit-manipulation

I have a table1 with columns as C1, C2, C3 and C4

All these columns stores bit value(true or false).

How to write a select query which uses the logical operations on these columns and gets me the final result?

Ex.:

```
Select ((C1 OR C2) AND (C3 OR C4)) AS FinalResult
from table1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bitwise Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) are supported for `bit` columns:

```
Select ((C1 | C2) & (C3 | C4)) AS FinalResult
from table1
```

When both operands are `bit`, the result is going to be same as if logical operators were applied.

Comment: +1 Assumes the columns aren't nullable though. `1 | NULL` is `NULL` whereas `TRUE or UNKNOWN` would be `TRUE`

Answer (score 1):

Just test to see if it is equal to 1 (true):

```
Select CASE WHEN (C1 = 1 OR C2 = 1) AND (C3 = 1 OR C4 = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FinalResult
from table1
```